# Disabling Keyboard-interactive SSH login

Tags: ssh, freebsd

I am trying to disable Keyboard-Interactive login, as I only want key login, but it won't disable with the below sshd_config. I also have attached an edited ssh -v login to the server.

I have been trying to follow [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/sshd-still-allowing-password-authentication.66129/), [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/ssh-access-to-freebsd-machine.53285/), and the [documentation here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config)

sshd_config:

```
MaxAuthTries 3
PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM no



Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

Edited ssh -v output:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to *.*.*.* [*.*.*.*] port **.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9 FreeBSD-20200214
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 FreeBSD-20200214 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to *.*.*.*:** as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:qDEr5lkrjAHt0jMrLosrpQEPP5s0BdC0+7CHyRl3+oY
debug1: Host '*.*.*.*' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password for user@server:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
Password for user@server:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
Password for user@server:
Received disconnect from *.*.*.* port *:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from *.*.*.* port **
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but did you restart sshd since you made that config?

Comment: Yes, both restarted the service and restarted the machine several times each.

Comment: use sshd -T to dump and check the config.

Answer (score 0):

This is mine. It works. It accepts s/key only.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Content of the config file:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand none
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
KerberosAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM no
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
```

System details:

```
   Static hostname: computer-vm
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: fe4c0783347b4ee48653e32703783aea
           Boot ID: a797d784ca274687b994312785a33879
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Rocky Linux 8.6 (Green Obsidian)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:rocky:rocky:8:GA
            Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```